# Why does the OSGi model based Eclipse need to restart after install a new plug-in?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, osgi, equinox

Eclipse is designed base on OSGi model. And the OSGi model declaim it supports hot install and uninstall bundles. So I am confused why the Eclipse always need to restart to take a new install plug-in work. Is the OSGi model not that good or Eclipse not implemented the whole model?

Answer (score 1):

The OSGi model works very well, but dynamics doesn't come for free. Bundle code needs to be written in such a way as to cope with services coming and going.

Eclipse has two problems. First there are an awful lot of legacy plugins that are not dynamic-aware and are written by frankly mediocre developers. Second, Eclipse has always shunned the services part of OSGi, instead favouring the "extension registry" with its a more static and clunky lifecycle (actually it's *possible* to handle dynamic updates with the extension registry, but much harder than when using OSGi services).

Actually in many cases Eclipse can dynamically cope with the addition of plugins, which is why the install dialog gives you the option to do this. But because of the variable quality of third party plugins, it plays safe and recommends a restart.